# Pass a model (or class) into a function and have it return an IOrderedEnumerable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am currently setting an `IOrderedEnumerable` variable called `properties`  below. I would like to create a function that I can pass `OrdersDemo.Models.facility_customer_orders` into and have it return the `IOrderedEnumerable`. I have tried to get this to work but failed.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to create the function?

```
var properties = typeof(OrdersDemo.Models.facility_customer_orders).GetProperties()
.Where(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(AdditionalModelAttributes), false))
.Select(p => new
{
    globalColumnName = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AdditionalModelAttributes), true).Cast<AdditionalModelAttributes>().FirstOrDefault().GlobalColumnName,
    displayHeaderName = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AdditionalModelAttributes), true).Cast<AdditionalModelAttributes>().FirstOrDefault().DisplayHeaderName,
    displayOrder = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AdditionalModelAttributes), true).Cast<AdditionalModelAttributes>().FirstOrDefault().DisplayDisplayOrder,
    displayFKTable = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AdditionalModelAttributes), true).Cast<AdditionalModelAttributes>().FirstOrDefault().DisplayFKTable,
    displayFKLookupIdColumn = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AdditionalModelAttributes), true).Cast<AdditionalModelAttributes>().FirstOrDefault().DisplayFKLookupIdColumn,
    displayFKLookupDisplayColumn = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AdditionalModelAttributes), true).Cast<AdditionalModelAttributes>().FirstOrDefault().DisplayFKLookupDisplayColumn
})
.OrderBy(o => o.displayOrder);
```

This is what I would like to accomplish:
This would be my new call. I have a class named `AdditionalModelAttributeMethods` and a method called `GetAdditionalAttributes`.

```
var properties = AdditionalModelAttributeMethods.GetAdditionalAttributes(OrdersDemo.Models.facility_customer_orders);
```

My method would look something like this:

```
public IOrderedEnumerable<dynamic> GetAdditionalAttributes(class aModel)
    {
        return typeof(aModel).GetProperties()
        .Where(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(AdditionalModelAttributes), false))
        .Select(p => new
        {
            globalColumnName = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AdditionalModelAttributes), true).Cast<AdditionalModelAttributes>().FirstOrDefault().GlobalColumnName,
            displayHeaderName = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AdditionalModelAttributes), true).Cast<AdditionalModelAttributes>().FirstOrDefault().DisplayHeaderName,
            displayOrder = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AdditionalModelAttributes), true).Cast<AdditionalModelAttributes>().FirstOrDefault().DisplayDisplayOrder,
            displayFKTable = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AdditionalModelAttributes), true).Cast<AdditionalModelAttributes>().FirstOrDefault().DisplayFKTable,
            displayFKLookupIdColumn = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AdditionalModelAttributes), true).Cast<AdditionalModelAttributes>().FirstOrDefault().DisplayFKLookupIdColumn,
            displayFKLookupDisplayColumn = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AdditionalModelAttributes), true).Cast<AdditionalModelAttributes>().FirstOrDefault().DisplayFKLookupDisplayColumn
        })
       .OrderBy(o => o.displayOrder);

    }
```

I'm having trouble converting the input and output types to take in the class and return the `IEnumerableList` to my variable `properties`.

Comment: is there any exception or the result is not expected?

Comment: I've tried to set up the function multiple ways, but I am unable to get it to successfully compile. I need some guidance on what I should pass to the function so that it will return the IOrderedEnumerable.

Comment: `unable to get it to successfully compile` - this means some error should be present, your code looks fairly fine to me except that it's a little verbose.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The code I posted is working. What I am trying to do is create a function that I can pass the model into and have it return the IOrderedEnumerable. For example: var properties = SomeFunctionName (OrdersDemo.Models.facility_customer_orders);

Comment: I understand your problem, the answer below is what you should follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some options, in order of general acceptance:

1. Create a concrete class to represent the class and use `IEnumerable<{type}>` as the return type of your function.
2. Set the return type to `IEnumerable<dynamic>`.  You can at least reference the properties in the calling code, although the calls won't be bound until run-time,
3. Use `IEnumerable<object>` as the return type.  The calling code will have to use reflection to access the properties.

Since you are just querying several properties of a `AdditionalModelAttributes`, you *could* just do

```
var properties = typeof(OrdersDemo.Models.facility_customer_orders).GetProperties()
.Where(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(AdditionalModelAttributes), false))
.Select(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AdditionalModelAttributes), true)
              .Cast<AdditionalModelAttributes>()
              .FirstOrDefault())
.OrderBy(o => o.DisplayDisplayOrder);
```

and use the return type of `IEnumerable<AdditionalModelAttributes>`, but you haven't given enough information to determine if that's the proper method.

Since you seem determined not to use a concrete type, the *minimum* change you need to make in your method is:

```
public IEnumerable<dynamic> GetAdditionalAttributes(object aModel)
{
    return aModel.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Where(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(AdditionalModelAttributes), false))
    ...
```

Comment: @D Stanley, I edited my original post to include an example of what I'm trying to accomplish. Does this fit into one of the options you suggest? If so, what am I missing? I am unable to properly pass the model into the method and return the models attributes as an IOrderedEnumerable.

Comment: @ChadRoland you cannot pass class like that, what you want is generic method with type argument, it looks like this `GetAdditionalAttributes<T>()`. You can even add some constraint on `T`. Inside `properties` should be `typeof(T).GetProperties()`. Call the method like this `GetAdditionalyAttributes<OrdersDemo.Models.facility_customer_orders>()`.

Comment: @ChadRoland I have corrected the syntax errors in your example - but I _strongly_ recommend you create a concrete type instead of returning a collection of an anonymous type. It's well worth the extra efort to have compile-time type safety.

Comment: I think this `OrdersDemo.Models.facility_customer_orders` is a class name, not an object (the OP used `typeof` against that). So he actually wants to pass a class in his method, not an object. So generic method should be used.

Comment: @Hopeless I'me asked for clarification - but why is generics necessary?  Passing in a `Type` would work just as well.

Comment: @D Stanley, thank you for the syntax help. It is my intention to create a concrete class. I will try reworking the AdditionalModelAttributeMethods class to behave that way and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return anonymous type. Create concrete type and return it.

Comment: this looks correct, the OP should have posted the whole his method and mentioned about the error, too concentrating on the result of the query blinded me from finding out this answer.

Comment: Alexander do you have an example of what the syntax would look like? I've tried multiple ways and am unable to create the type from within the function and return it.

Comment: @ChadRoland you cannot do that, you need a type defined outside.

Comment: How do I solve my issue then? The code snippet in the original post is going to be used on many pages and will have many other attributes added to it. My goal is to take the model that is being used on the page, pass it into a function and have it return the list of attributes tied to the model.

Comment: @ChadRoland declare a class such as `public class OrderInfo { ... }`, then instead of `new {....}` you need to project to `new OrderInfo { .... }`. That's all. Define all properties (in the anonymous type) in the `OrderInfo` class.